# Suma lento en python - Optimizar

Tags: python

Tengo esta data en un dataframe en Python:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando calcular una media móvil simple de la columna 'Close' y que el valor se añada como una nueva columna del dataframe. Este es el código que estoy utilizando.

```
def var_mms(df):
        df['MMS_50'] = df['Close']

        for i in range(50-1, len(df)):
            df.at[i,'MMS_50'] = (df.loc[i-50+1:i,'Close'].sum()) / rango

        return df
```

El problema que me encuentro es que mi dataframe tiene 150k líneas y esta operación (creo que es el .sum()) tarda mucho. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto de una forma más eficiente?

Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema no es tanto el `.sum()` como la iteración en bucle.

**Evita iterar** siempre que sea posible. Pandas tiene montones de funciones que hacen la iteración por ti y que están programadas en C por lo que son mucho más rápidas. Busca siempre antes si hay ya alguna función pandas que haga  lo que buscas. En este caso la hay y se llama [`df.rolling()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)

Veamos un ejemplo. Primero voy a preparar un dataframe con 150k valores como el tuyo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

numeros = np.random.random(size=150000)*4+20

df = pd.DataFrame({"Closing": numeros })
```

Podemos ver su comienzo:

```
     Closing
0  22.954062
1  20.594166
2  22.054883
3  20.708241
4  22.643817
```

Para calcular la media móvil con una ventana de 50 basta hacer:

```
df['MMS_50'] = df["Closing"].rolling(50).mean()
```

Esta línea se ejecuta en una fracción de segundo. Podemos ver el resultado (los primeros 50 valores son `NaN`, así que muestro del 50 en adelante):

```
      Closing     MMS_50
50  20.410513  21.976568
51  23.730935  22.039303
52  20.162057  22.001447
53  23.826258  22.063807
54  20.429890  22.019528
```

Como no se ve gran cosa que demuestre que los valores estén bien, pinto una gráfica de los 1000 primeros valores:

```
df[:1000].plot(figsize=(12, 4))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]